# What is an explicit function that fails the Hardy inequality at $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

To be explicit, let $f \in L^1(0,1)$ and define $g(t) : = \frac{1}{1-t} \int_t^1 f(s) ds$. A version of Hardy's inequality shows that for any $ 1 < p < \infty$,

$
\Vert g \Vert_{L^p(0,1)} \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \Vert f \Vert_{L^p(0,1)}
$

Can we pick $f$ such that $g \notin L^1$? The natural guess $f(t) = t^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha < 1$ does not work, and

By using some martingale trickery, it can be shown using Doob's maximal inequality that

$
\Vert g \Vert_{L^1(0,1)} \leq \frac{e}{e-1} \Big\{ 1 + \Vert |f| \log_+ |f| \Vert_{L^1(0,1)}\Big\}
$

so the function above must satisfy at least $f \notin L^1 \log L^1$.